# Why does this ciphertext always start with the same characters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cryptography, cryptojs

I started toying with CryptoJS, and I noticed something strange: the ciphertext always starts with the same string of characters. Here is the code to perform the encryption (I know Math.random isn't cryptographically secure, this was just something quick and dirty).

```
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.Text = "";
    $scope.CipherText = "";
    $scope.Key = Math.random().toString();

    $scope.Encrypt = function ($event) {
        $scope.CipherText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($scope.Text, $scope.Key).toString();
    }
}
```

With the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div>Your key is: "{{Key}}".</div>
    <div>
        <textarea ng-change="Encrypt()" ng-model="Text" maxlength="140">{{Text}}</textarea>
        <br />
        <span>{{Text.length}} of 140</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea ng-model="CipherText" maxlength="216">{{CipherText}}</textarea>
        <br />
        <span>{{CipherText.length}} of 216</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

After a few runs, I noticed that the base64 ciphertext always started with the same few characters. For the key `0.5640227501280606`:

```
a: U2FsdGVkX19kMKXVbnJHKbEkrwctAm2YbOTnPmtGRCg=
b: U2FsdGVkX18+0sG2DQzVgHwxH2cvrSqaDIxOOkUt5YU=
c: U2FsdGVkX19xGQdT6OUhbyyg1zfgqpGnWvF5Ibqkuqc=
```

I've tried this with different keys, and different length plaintexts. The ciphertext always begins with `U2FsdGVkX1`. What's going on here? Is CryptoJS storing some internal information here? Or is this normal for AES under certain circumstances?

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1, which means it's always `0.*******`, so the first characters probably reflects the fact that every key starts with `0.`

Comment: @adeneo That's a good idea, so I tried replacing the key with a phrase and still found the result prefixed with the same string.

Comment: `U2FsdGVkX` actually decodes to `salted_`, so it's  a string added by the crypto function, that's all.

Comment: And knowing what to search for helps, and I found a similar question -> http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15110/cryptojs-aes-result-always-has-same-first-few-bytes

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y76Be/1/

Comment: @adeneo Good catch. I searched SO but I never thought to search related SE sites.

Comment: It came up when searching google for `Salted_` and `AES`, so it sort of confirmed my suspicion, but strange thing to do, adding a salt like that ?

Comment: Very odd, they must be using internally to modify how the encryption/decryption is done. I can't imagine any other purpose for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decoding the strings, it seems

```
U2FsdGVkX19
```

decodes to

```
Salted_
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y76Be/2/)

so it's just a string added by CryptoJS as a salt

Comment: It's actually two underscores, but because one underscore shares two bits with the next (random) byte value in base 64, the next character does appear to be random as well. It's not a salt in itself, it is a "magic" that indicates that a salt was used.

Answer (score 2):

The initial String added to the ciphertext is `"Salted__"` (without the quotes, two underscores at the end), indicating that *the next eight bytes* are the salt value, followed by the ciphertext.

This is likely to keep binary compatibility with OpenSSL which does the same if a password is used instead of a key. The key is then derived using [`EVP_BytesToKey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) function`. This is a proprietary protocol of OpenSSL, it is not a standardized method of adding a salt or deriving a key from a password.